# Parent MySQL Table with Child Table with list of images can I have the child table as an array in parent table?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, rest

If i have a parent MySQL table with the following setup:
ID | Name | Description

and I have a child table with 
Parent_ID | Tag

There could be multiple rows of Tag's with the same parent_ID.

How could I do a SQL Query to return the complete Parent Table, but also include the parent_id Tags as array 
ie:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "name",
    "description": "description",
    "tag": [
      "tag1",
      "tag2",
      "tag3"
    ]
  }
]
```

I am using PHP to create a rest API, would I do the array and join in php or would i do this in MySQL.  Is there any advantage to returning the query with an array of all of the matching tags by parent ID? or would It be better to just have a second rest end point for tag by id and just get tags that way and handle the display in the UI layer.  any thoughts would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the GROUP_CONCAT function to create a comma separated list of values:

```
SELECT 
    a.`id`,
    a.`name`,
    a.`description`,
    GROUP_CONCAT(b.`Tag`) as `tags`
FROM `parent` a
JOIN `child` b
ON a.`id` = b.`parent_id`
GROUP BY a.`id`, a.`name`, a.`description`;
```

Comment: good to go, won't let me accept for 3 min. but i just tested it and thats what I need. thanks

Comment: is there a way to put them as their own item in the tag, so its tags with an array instead of tags with comma's  so I could reuse this same concept for same a group of images in array or something that isn't just all in 1 item with,  or would I then have to parse that value and remove the comman and split it back out in my UI

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Accept when you can. Thanks!

Comment: MySQL doesn't have arrays as such. But in PHP it's easy to convert to/from an array using implode/explode. At least in your results, you'll only have one row per parent.

Comment: ok thanks, that kinda my original question is that would i have to do the array creation in php and not mySQL but your answer is good enough.  thanks